# In Microsoft excel

Tags: excel

I want use two logic in one cell in spreadsheet. 1st logic: ((last no. -- first no.) +1) and 2 nd logic is I will give input in either last or first no. cell it should give result as 1.what formula I can use?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the IF operator. This article gives a bit of a tutorial on it:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

If you are looking to decide which operation to take, the if operator is what you need.

To take two separate operations and combine their result, use a simple plus symbol:

```
=IF(a1=4,1,2)+ IF(a2=4,10,20)
```

Should output various different outputs based upon the values of a1 and a2. You can additionally nest equations and branching logic inside the if statements.

Note that your original question has a bit of ambiguity in it, but this is a quick answer.